# How to change only one label when condition met in a table of records on form in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want to display a label of a particular record in a form that displays all the records being red when a certain condition, such as date/time being some date/time, is met. I know how to change the forecolor and such, but I want to change one specific label where the date/time is some value. Is this possible? If so, how would I do it?

Here is the code:

```
Dim lbl As Control
For Each lbl In Me.Controls
    If lbl.ControlType = acLabel Then
    If CInt(Me.NameTxt.Value) = 1 Then
        lbl.ForeColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Else
        lbl.ForeColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)

    End If
End If
Next lbl
```

It turns all labels red instead of the record labels. How do I fix this?

Comment: Here is my code in the OnCurrent event:    Dim lbl As Control
    For Each lbl In Me.Controls
        If lbl.ControlType = acLabel Then
        If CInt(Me.NameTxt.Value) = 1 Then
            lbl.ForeColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        Else
            lbl.ForeColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
        
        End If
    End If
    Next lbl     However, even when there is only one that fits the condition, all labels are turned red.

Comment: Well, look at your code.. You're saying: "For **all** labels in my form's collection of Controls, if Me.NameTxt = 1, make everything red"

Comment: Well, then how do I make it so that only the label with the corresponding NameTxt is changed instead of all of them?

Comment: I would give the label you're concerned about a specific name, and change it specifically.

Comment: What do you mean? In MS Access, the form has only a template of what each record will be displayed as, and that template is used to display all the records in a table. How do I change only one label based on the value of the corresponding textbox value?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78120/discussion-between-user3864563-and-invent-animate).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there is the ability to use Conditinoal Formmating, which allows one to make expressions for a form so that a label changes formatting when a condition is met. It can be found in the Form Design tab in MS Access 2010.